# Pycharm: Cursor multiline selection as block

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2018.2. Instead of my cursor selecting text by considering the serial aspect of the text in a file, i.e. selection by series. It considers the 2D aspect of a screen and selects text as a block. I don't know what it is called, nor how to fix this. Otherwise I would be able to find the setting myself. To explain better here are some images.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I18b.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Fx6.png)

I have unselected everything to do with virtual spaces in preferences/general. Otherwise I have not found anything useful.

Comment: It would be better to paste the code to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer! Select Edit and uncheck Column Selection Mode. It has the hotkey Command + Shift + 8 so I must have pressed it by accident.